# Why does warp return HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed for incorrectly typed parameters?

Tags: rest, http, curl, rust, rust-warp

Consider the following route specification in warp:

```rust
let read_book_route = warp::path!("book" / Address)
        .and(warp::get())
        .and(warp::any().map(move || read_book_state.clone()))
        .and_then(handler::read_book_handler);
```

If a non-`Address` is provided in the URL, warp automatically returns a HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed status code:

```sh
$ curl -i http://example.com/book/not_a_valid_address
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 23
date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 06:22:20 GMT

HTTP method not allowed
```

Why HTTP 405? Why not HTTP 400, or any other client error?

Comment: Playing your question back to you: Which of the [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) you'll find more appropriate __and why__?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich in my mind a 404 would probably be more appropriate: the resource doesn't exist, that the method is not applicable to the non-existing resource is quite secondary.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich 400, perhaps? Given the request is technically invalid (admittedly at an application level).

Comment: @sporejack: 400 is about a malformed request from the perspective of the HTTP protocol, thus it would not be a good match. In general though there is no error matching perfectly the problem - and it is actually not that relevant what exact error code gets used as long it clearly means that an error occurred in the first place and that the client is to blame for this (i.e. 4xx code vs. 5xx code).

Answer (score 1):

[`path!`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.0/warp/macro.path.html) can be understood as a sequence of [`path()`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.0/warp/filters/path/fn.path.html) and [`param()`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.0/warp/filters/path/fn.param.html) capped by an [`end()`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.0/warp/filters/path/fn.end.html) (by default), and according to the documentation of `param()`:

> If the value could not be parsed, rejects with a `404 Not Found`.

**However** AFAIK this is a [`Rejection`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.0/warp/reject/struct.Rejection.html), which means that warp will then try the next filter `or`-ed with this one and get *its* rejection.

Since you don't provide a *minimal reproduction example* and don't show all your code either, I would expect there to be other filters, and I don't quite know how warp processes combined rejections, nor do I know if you have e.g. an intermediate [`recover`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.0/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.recover) which could intercept the `not_found` which `param()` would produce, and let an other rejection take priority instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% (some context lacks), but could be related to this issue: https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues/77 (It has also some possible workarounds proposed)

Since filters form a tree, if one branch fails with rejection, neighbour branch can be tried as well. Warp has priority of rejections. And `MethodNotAllowed` has higher priority compared to to `NotFound`. So if path is not matched to one branch with `NotFound`, as with different parameter type, `warp` will try other paths - and overwrite rejection with `MethodNotAllowed` since other branch has other method.

You can run server with trace log level with `RUST_LOG=trace cargo run` and check how filter matching is executed.